# Loop cut and slide ignores a face, why?

Tags: modeling

I just want to know why loop cut and slide ignores the face in the picture and how to fix it. I have checked and found no extra vertexes and i have already tried w--remove doubles and that didn't fix the problem.

Here's the model: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/40904

And here's the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPwUP.jpg):
[image]

Thanks in advance

I have already checked the other questions that's similar to this one and the answers didn't help.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue on the file you uploaded: http://i.stack.imgur.com/03ReQ.gif

Comment: I dont have that problem, but you have N-gons in other places that will stop the loopcuts

Comment: wow strange, what do you think it is

Comment: Usually when a loop cut like that does't work is because there are duplicated edges/faces/vertices or there is an n-gon somewhere

Comment: but it worked for you

Comment: can it have something with my mac to do

Comment: cegaton you deleted a face, when i deleted the face it worked for me too but is there a way for me to loop cut without deleting the face?

Comment: Maybe a bug in your version of blender where you have faces extruded from the surface.

Comment: @Thecoolguy I oppened your file and tried a loop cut... nothing else.